# Add a new namespace prefix to the body of a SOAP request, that is not present or referenced in the original XML

Tags: web-services, xslt, soap

I have XML list of values that will be populated by a form.  Based on the value of a particular element, in this case **Type**, I need to dynamically construct a SOAP request. Only certain elements from the Source XML will be used, contingent on the **Type**.   In addition, I need to add a namespace prefix to every element in the SOAP body that is not present or referenced in any way in the Source XML.

Given XML input in the following format:

```
<User>
    <Action>Update</Action>
    <Id>123-45-5678</Id>
    <Type>Student</Type>
    <Validate>true</Validate>
    <Grade>11</Grade>
    <Classroom/>
    <UserName/>
    <Password/>
</User>
```

If I apply the following transform:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:ztx="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="Action" select="/User/Action"/>
    <xsl:variable name="Id"     select="/User/Id"/>
    <xsl:variable name="Type"   select="/User/Type"/>
    <xsl:variable name="Method" select="concat('ztx:', $Action, $Type)"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
            <soapenv:Header/>
            <soapenv:Body>
                <xsl:element name="{$Method}">
                    <xsl:if test="$Action != 'Create'">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="/User/Id"/>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="$Action != 'Delete'">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="$Type = 'Teacher'">
                                <xsl:copy-of select="/User/Classroom"/>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:when test="$Type = 'Student'">
                                <xsl:copy-of select="/User/Grade"/>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:when test="$Type = 'Administrator'">
                                <xsl:copy-of select="/User/UserName"/>
                                <xsl:copy-of select="/User/Password"/>
                            </xsl:when>
                        </xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="/User/Validate"/>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:element>
            </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I get the following output:

```
<soapenv:Envelope  xmlns:ztx="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ztx:UpdateStudent>
            <Id>123-45-5678</Id>
            <Grade>11</Grade>
            <Validate>true</Validate>
        </ztx:UpdateStudent>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

My desired output, however, is:

```
<soapenv:Envelope  xmlns:ztx="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ztx:UpdateStudent>
            <ztx:Id>123-45-5678</ztx:Id>
            <ztx:Grade>11</ztx:Grade>
            <ztx:Validate>true</ztx:Validate>
        </ztx:UpdateStudent>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I would like to do this elegantly, if possible, and in a single transform.  Looking for a generic way, perhaps with another template, to just process every element in the SOAP body and add the namespace, rather than hard-code them individually.

NOTE: I am restricted to XSLT 1.0

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you mentioned in your question you can add another template to add the namespace prefix to the elements for your SOAP response.

Here is the template

```
<xsl:template name="addNamespace" match="User/*">
  <xsl:element name="{concat('ztx:',name(.))}">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

And then you would just change all of your `copy-of` to `apply-templates` then to use the new template.